# how to substring a variable string

Tags: scala

suppose I have a variable

```
var variable="[123]"
```

how to substring only get

`123` without the `[]`

Comment: `variable.init.tail`

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
variable.stripPrefix("[").stripSuffix("]")
res0: String = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using `.substring`

```
variable.substring(1, variable.length-1)
```

And the result is:

```
res0: String = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regex pattern to extract the contents

```
val str = "[123]".replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", "$1");
```

This will fetch you an output

```
str: String = 123
```